# extract value from html form

Tags: regex, sed, cmd

i have an huge html file, where i try to extract a spezific value from a unique input form.

```
...    
<input type="hidden" name="wpLoginToken" value="9ae61b0c5de20b418895d5301f6a1517" />
"editToken":"4087c77c53bbedbb1015946281fe8b99+\\"
....
```

the name is wpLoginToken  and i want the only `9ae61b0c5de20b418895d5301f6a1517`
the second editToken and want the only `4087c77c53bbedbb1015946281fe8b99+\\`

Currently i try it using sed.

for the first

```
s/"wpLoginToken".*value="\([^"]*\)".*/\1/
```

for the second

```
s/"editToken":"\([^"]*\)".*/\1/
```

But in both cases i get the whole file..

Any Ideas?

Thanks

Comment: All you needed was the -n option and p for print at the end and you probably would have figured the rest out, you were close but sed -n 's/"wpLoginToken".*value="\([^"]*\)".*/\1/p' makes sed get confused because you match multiple previous patterns so it gives you the biggest match and returns:  <input type="hidden" name=9ae61b0c5de20b418895d5301f6a1517  instead if you limit it to something like sed -n 's/.*value="\([^"]*\)".*/\1/p' n1.txt you will get the answer you were looking for 9ae61b0c5de20b418895d5301f6a1517

Answer (score 0):

Don’t use `sed`. This and any of your future web scraping will go way easier if you switch to the right tools. For example:

- `python` for the language
- `lxml` for its nice beautifulsoup parser
- **XPath** for searching in a tree of HTML elements
- **ElementTree** for looking in and around an element

A program using these would look like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

from lxml.html.soupparser import parse

tree = parse(file('index.html'))
# XPath: “look for an <input> element with ‘name’ attribute equal ‘wpLoginToken’”
element = tree.xpath('//input[@name="wpLoginToken"]')[0]
print(element.value)

data = element.tail.split('"')
print(data[3])
```

Which gives you:

```
9ae61b0c5de20b418895d5301f6a1517
4087c77c53bbedbb1015946281fe8b99+\\
```

**Note:** Install these packages on a linux system:

- `python`
- `python-lxml`

Answer (score 0):

```
sed -n '/[wpLogin|editToken]/{s/.*".*"\(.*\)".*/\1/p}'  <file>
```

The first part matches the tokens and the second looks for a pair of quotation marks with anything in between, if you cant rely on the quotes then you can change that to something more specific.